# Round Rect UIBarButton in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, uibarbuttonitem

I Am trying to create a UIBarButton as a flat Round Rect. sort of a mix between iOS 7 and 6.
Heres an example from the Facebook app
[image: Example Button]

I want a Button that looks like the "send" button.
Anyone has any idea?

Im actually surprised that Apple don't give this option for us while they use it in quite a few places. sometimes just writing in colour is not enough to make the user understand its a button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were to put a `UIButton` inside a `UIBarButtonItem` and set the `backgroundColor`, then you could use the `cornerRadius` property of it's `layer`:

```
self.button.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
```

In order for this to work, you need the CoreGraphics.framework and `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just provide a custom button background image with rounded corners and set it as the background image inside the storyboard.